# Parse JSON in java (custom)

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I have a JSON array in the following format:

```
[["1234","OS","01/31/2023","02/01/2023","First Day"],["1245","OS","01/23/2023","01/24/2023","Last Day"],["3411","OS","09/21/2022","09/21/2022","Second Day"]]
```

In Java, I would like to parse this array and store data in the following format:

```
String[] firstElements = ["1234" , "1245", "3411"];
String[] secondElements = ["OS", "OS", "OS"];
String[] thirdElements = ["01/31/2023", "01/23/2023", "09/21/2022"];
String[] fourthElements = ["02/01/2023", "01/24/2023", "09/21/2022"];
String[] fifthElements = ["First Day", "Last Day", "Second Day"];
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sure, I don't see anything that would make this impossible. What did you try so far? You might have to parse the input into 3 arrays first and then do the transposing yourself though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        String jsonArray = "[[\"1234\",\"OS\",\"01/31/2023\",\"02/01/2023\",\"First Day\"],[\"1245\",\"OS\",\"01/23/2023\",\"01/24/2023\",\"Last Day\"],[\"3411\",\"OS\",\"09/21/2022\",\"09/21/2022\",\"Second Day\"]]";
        
        JsonArray array = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonArray)).readArray();
        List<String> firstElements = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> secondElements = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> thirdElements = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fourthElements = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fifthElements = new ArrayList<>();
        
        array.forEach( value -> {
            JsonArray innerArray = value.asJsonArray();
            firstElements.add(innerArray.getString(0));
            secondElements.add(innerArray.getString(1));
            thirdElements.add(innerArray.getString(2));
            fourthElements.add(innerArray.getString(3));
            fifthElements.add(innerArray.getString(4));

        )};
```

If you want something more generic you can use a `List<List<String>>`

```
String jsonArray = "[[\"1234\",\"OS\",\"01/31/2023\",\"02/01/2023\",\"First Day\"],[\"1245\",\"OS\",\"01/23/2023\",\"01/24/2023\",\"Last Day\"],[\"3411\",\"OS\",\"09/21/2022\",\"09/21/2022\",\"Second Day\"]]";

JsonArray array = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonArray)).readArray();
List<List<String>> elements = new ArrayList<>();

array.forEach( value -> {
    JsonArray innerArray = value.asJsonArray();
    List<String> subElements = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < innerArray.size(); i++) {
        subElements.add(innerArray.getString(i));
    }
    elements.add(subElements);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to parsing JSON from Java, like [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson), though if the data format you are working with is simple enough and you don't have to parse all kinds of JSON, you might as well parse it by yourself.